# Increase security with Paypal payment

Tags: php, forms, paypal

I have this code on my Website:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="itemname" value="1" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="itemnumber" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="itemQty" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="17"> 
</form>
```

This code, sends a POST to process.php, which opens a paypal class to make the payment.

All works great, but I have a very big trouble. The point is, if I edit any value with FireBug, let's say for example, "itemprice", anyone can change the default value, and replace the itemprice with any other quantity at the moment of process the payment.

How could I fix this? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: all payment gateways have this issue to a greater or lesser extent, you always have to validate the payment amount

Answer (score 0):

Encryption is the only way to thwart this, there's nothing you can do client side.  You could try to add some verification server side or use the _SESSION, but those are your only options.

Comment: The common option is to encrypt the server side, I guess? Well, already tried it, it works. But if I switch 2 "itemprices" I can buy the "product 1" with the same price as "product 2".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PayPal Instant Payment Notification System (IPN). You supply the URL to a script on your website which can handle the payment. It is there somewhere when you login to your PayPal account.

Every time a new payment is made PayPal will send a request to your IPN script with all the details of the payment (item ID,name, price, whatever you want and you can then verify in the script using your database if the prices match for the supplied item ID's.

It is very easy to implement in my opinion and very flexible. It is very well documented too on the PayPal website. It does not take too long to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You should never rely on the price from the web form. Because the item has its ID, it's perfectly valid to send only the ID and required quantity to the process.php. This, in turn, should fetch the prices straight from the source (database, config...), not from the (possibly tampered) web form data.